# Recreating Elastic Index with different Field Type

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data, elastic-stack, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm new to ES currently attempting to use spring-data-elasticsearch 3.2.1.RELEASE in my service.
Design is still in early phase and hence I've had to change/update fields in the ElasticDocument which we annotate by @Document.
It looks somewhat like:

```
@Docuemnt(...)
public class MyDocument {
    @Id
    private String id;

    ...

    @Field(type = FieldType.String, name = "myField")
    private String myField;
}
```

I had to change days field to an object, for which I simply changed the Datatype and FieldType Attribute to Object.

```
@Docuemnt(...)
public class MyDocument {
    @Id
    private String id;

    ...

    @Field(type = FieldType.Object, name = "myField")
    private Object myField;
}
```

I deleted all documents from my index on cluster and attempted to save this document with new field type but it looks like it's still giving errors due to previous type being Text.

```
org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: Bulk indexing has failures. 
Use ElasticsearchException.getFailedDocuments() for detailed messages 
[
  {
    XYZ=ElasticsearchException[
      Elasticsearch exception [
        type=mapper_parsing_exception,
        reason=failed to parse field [myField] of type [text] in document with id 'XYZ']
      ];
      nested: ElasticsearchException[
        Elasticsearch exception [
          type=illegal_state_exception,
          reason=Can't get text on a START_OBJECT at 1:296          ]
      ];
  }
]
```

I'm pretty sure this might not be the best practice to change Field Types but I have tried this with a different indexName and that worked.

For another attempt, deleting this particular index manually and letting spring data elasticsearch create it while doing bulk indexing does not help. I see the same error.

Could it be because I have more instances (non-local) which are connected to elastic though not doing any operations on this index at this moment?

Comment: normally deleting and recreating the index should be enough, as the index mapping is newly created then. What do you mean with "other instances which are connected to Elastic"?

Comment: There are more instances of my Spring Boot Microservice, apart from the one I'm running locally. They all establish connection to elastic, though I'm sure they don't do any operations on the index I'm trying to manipulate from my local instance of service.